# Circumscribed (irregular) pentagon

Tags: geometry, polygons

You're given the consecutive lengths of the sides of an irregular pentagon, and you want to circumscribe this pentagon (whose interior angles are unknown yet) about a circle of unknown radius.

Is there a known procedure to do this ?

The image below is one that I created in Microsoft Excel using VBA code that implements a Newton-Raphson iteration in the the five interior angles of the pentagon, using consecutive side lengths of $3, 6, 6, 3, 2 $.

[image]

Comment: No, I think there is a unique radius given the sides of the pentagon, not a maximum radius.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm concerned about, the use of *circumscribed*.  Consider first a unit square and the circle of unit *diameter* inscribed in that square.  Now cut off a tiny right isosceles triangle from one corner of the square, giving an irregular pentagon that encloses the original circle.  Would you still say the pentagon is circumscribed about that circle?

Comment: I think you clarified (in commenting on a now deleted Answer) that the pentagon is *flexible* to the extent that all the side lengths are preserved in order, and you seek to arrange the edges so that a circle is tangent to all five of them.

Comment: Let $t_i$ be the distance of $i^{th}$ vertex to nearby contact points of pentagon/circle. you can compute $t_i$ easily from the side lengths. If $R$ is radius of the circle, they will satisfy $\sum_i \tan^{-1}\frac{t_i}{R} = \pi$, you can turn this into a quadratic equation in $R^2$.

Comment: Thank you @achillehui . I'll work on this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Working on **achille hui** idea in his comment above, if $\theta_i$ is the angle connecting side $i$ to side $(i+1)$, where side 6 is side 1, then,

$\tan\left(\dfrac{\theta_i}{2}\right) = \dfrac{R}{x_{i+1}} \tag{1}$

where it is assumed that moving counter clockwise (for example) and segmenting the side $s_i$ to $s_i = x_i + x_{i+1} $ where the point of separation is the tangency point with the inscribed circle.

It is easy to construct a linear system to relate the $5$ $x_i$'s to the $5$ side lengths.

Now, we know that the sum of the interior angles in a pentagon is $3(180^\circ) = 540^\circ$, therefore the sum of half the angles is $270^\circ$

Further, the tangent of the sum of $5$ angles is given by [(see this Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Composition_of_trigonometric_functions)

$ \tan(\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 + \phi_4 + \phi_5) = \dfrac{ \sum t_i - \sum t_i t_j t_k + \sum t_i t_j t_k t_l t_m }{ 1 - \sum t_i t_j + \sum t_i t_j t_k t_l } $

where $t_i = \tan(\theta_i) $

Since $270^\circ$ has an infinite tangent, we want the denominator in the above expression to $0$.   The denominator is a function of $R^2$ because the $x_i's$ are known.  Hence we end up with a quadratic equation in $R^2$ which is trivial to solve.

Once $R$ is found, we can compute the center of the inscribed circle, and compute all the internal angles, and construct the pentagon and the inscribed circle.